# Android back button exits app react-native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I tried all the solution but my app doesn't trigger even the back handler listener. It simply just exits on clicking android back button. I am using firebase in these app.

React-native version : 0.55.4

Comment: Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You did not add any code, exception, stack trace.

Comment: please be specific with some piece of code

Comment: Actually this issue was not specifically of any code... I found out the solution. The issue was with firebase latest version, which was having issue in android back button integration. I downgraded the version of firebase and my app is working fine.

Comment: This issue is resolved, was due to firebase version it was occuring. Downgraded it and now it working fine

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this issue was not specifically of any code... I found out the solution. The issue was with firebase latest version, which was having issue in android back button integration. I downgraded the version of firebase and my app is working fine.